# How do I set the correlation sequence property on a mule message?

Tags: mule

I would like to sort messages coming from a jdbc query before aggregating them using a collection aggregator, I think the best way to do this is the resequencer.  When I add this line

```
<resequencer timeout="6000" failOnTimeout="false" />
```

the workflow produces this error:

> ************************************************************************** Message               : Execution of the expression
>   "message.payload.INVOICE_NUMBER" failed.
>   (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException). Message payload
>   is of type: MuleEvent[] Code                  : MULE_ERROR--2
>   -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Exception stack is:
>   1. [Lorg.mule.api.MuleEvent; cannot be cast to java.util.Map (java.lang.ClassCastException)
>   org.mvel2.optimizers.impl.refl.nodes.MapAccessor:42 (null)
>   2. [Error: cannot invoke getter: getPayload [declr.class: org.mule.el.context.MessageContext; act.class:
>   org.mule.el.context.MessageContext] (see trace)] [Near : {... Unknown
>   ....}]
>                ^ [Line: 1, Column: 0] (org.mvel2.CompileException)   org.mvel2.optimizers.impl.refl.nodes.GetterAccessor:75 (null)
>   3. Execution of the expression "message.payload.INVOICE_NUMBER" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException)
>   org.mule.el.mvel.MVELExpressionLanguage:211
>   (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/expression/ExpressionRuntimeException.html)
>   4. Execution of the expression "message.payload.INVOICE_NUMBER" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException). Message
>   payload is of type: MuleEvent[]
>   (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerMessagingException)
>   org.mule.transformer.AbstractTransformer:123
>   (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transformer/TransformerMessagingException.html)
>   -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Root Exception stack trace: java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   [Lorg.mule.api.MuleEvent; cannot be cast to java.util.Map     at
>   org.mvel2.optimizers.impl.refl.nodes.MapAccessor.getValue(MapAccessor.java:42)    at
>   org.mvel2.optimizers.impl.refl.nodes.GetterAccessor.getValue(GetterAccessor.java:41)
>     at
>   org.mvel2.optimizers.impl.refl.nodes.VariableAccessor.getValue(VariableAccessor.java:38)
>       + 3 more (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
>
> ---

```
<when expression="#[message.payload.LHF_INVOICE_METHOD == 'EDI']"><processor-chain>
        <message-properties-transformer doc:name="Set Correlation ID">
            <add-message-property key="MULE_CORRELATION_SEQUENCE" value="#[message.payload.INVOICE_NUMBER]" />
        </message-properties-transformer>
<resequencer timeout="6000" failOnTimeout="false" />
<set-payload value="#[message.payload.INVOICE_NUMBER]" doc:name="EDI"/>                                
<collection-aggregator  timeout="3200" failOnTimeout="false" doc:name="EDI"          storePrefix="EDI" />
<smtp:outbound-endpoint host="mail.example.com" to="test@example.com" from="muleservice@example.com" subject="[Invoice Workflow] EDI" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="EDI"/>
<collection-splitter doc:name="Collection Splitter"/>
<jdbc:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" queryKey="gMarkProcessedInRoss"     queryTimeout="1000" connector-ref="DatabaseMuleLogin" doc:name="Mark Processed in Ross">
</jdbc:outbound-endpoint>
</processor-chain>
</when>
```

I added a splitter after the resequencer (below) which works, except that the messages are still coming out unsorted on the email.

```
<set-property propertyName="MULE_CORRELATION_SEQUENCE" value="#[message.payload.INVOICE_NUMBER]" />
<resequencer timeout="6000" failOnTimeout="false" />
<collection-splitter doc:name="Collection Splitter"/>
<set-payload value="#[message.payload.message.payload.INVOICE_NUMBER]" doc:name="EDI"/>
<echo-component doc:name="Echo"/>                                
<collection-aggregator  timeout="3200" failOnTimeout="false" doc:name="EDI"  storePrefix="EDI"       />
<smtp:outbound-endpoint host="mail.example.com" to="test@example.com" from="muleservice@example.com" subject="[Invoice Workflow] EDI" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="EDI"/>
<collection-splitter doc:name="Collection Splitter"/>
<jdbc:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="one-way" queryKey="RouteEDI" queryTimeout="1000" connector-ref="DatabaseMuleLogin" doc:name="Mark Processed in Ross">
</jdbc:outbound-endpoint>
```

I added an echo component and they are coming out sorted at that point so I'm pretty sure the aggregator is unsorting them.

Comment: Copy/paste issue here: `"#    [message.payload.INVOICE_NUMBER]"`? (spaces between # and [).

Comment: Sort of, I had to add 4 spaces all over the place to get the code block working here... I double checked my original xml and there are no extra spaces after the # there.

Comment: Are the correlation group size and correlation ID correctly set on the messages? The resequencer only work if these two properties have relevant values. BTW `message-properties-transformer` is old style, use `set-property` instead.

Comment: Yes, both the group size and correlation id are set earlier in the flow.  The aggregator after the re-sequencer works fine (if I remove the resequencer).  I actually don't know the size of the group so I set it to 1000 and rely on the timeout, I'm hoping the timeout works with the resequencer?  I'll change to the set-property...  thanks.

Comment: Oh boy now I understand. If the resequencer times-out, it spits a *single* message whose _payload_ is an array of `MuleEvent`s. You need then to split this array with a `<collection-splitter />` and extract the original payload with `#[message.payload.message.payload]`.

Comment: Thanks, adding the splitter worked, but the messages in the email produced by the smtp component are coming through unsorted. I added an echo component and the messages are sorted after the resequencer so it appears the collection aggregator is unsorting them.

Comment: In that case, drop the split/aggregator after the resequencer and create an expression component that directly prepares the desired payload for the SMTP outbound endoint. It'll be way more direct and easier.

Comment: So, I assume that means I need to write my expression to parse through the array produced by the resequencer?  Do you by chance know of any sample code to do that, I didn't find a lot of information on accessing arrays from within Mule expressions.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, parse through the array. Read http://mvel.codehaus.org/Inline+List%2C+Maps+and+Arrays and http://mvel.codehaus.org/MVEL+2.0+Projections+and+Folds. Also I believe my response below is correct... please do accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, the correlation sequence property is named `MULE_CORRELATION_SEQUENCE`. You can set it as shown hereafter:

```
<set-property propertyName="MULE_CORRELATION_SEQUENCE"
              value="1" />
```

The resequencer should then order messages based on that sequence. If not, please update your question with the failing configuration.

Be sure to have the `MULE_CORRELATION_GROUP_SIZE` property set to the right size and that all the messages to resequence share the same `MULE_CORRELATION_ID` property.